# Issues using Mysql++ in a multithreaded environment

Tags: c++, linux, mysql++

Hoping someone could help me out, as I'm getting some 'weird' segmentation faults. I'm currently working on a C++ daemon that periodically processes incoming data from an input source, and then sends it back to a different system.

The daemon currently runs two threads - one thread (main thread) that reads incoming data from a message queue and that inserts processed data into an MySQL database, and a second one that reads from a specific table and pushes processed data to a different system.

I'm assuming the error is somehow related to MySQL and threading, because I have no issues when running one thread (just the data processing, or just pushing back the processed data).

The SIGSEGV errors are all mysql++ related (the first mysql++ method that is called after connecting to the DB), eg:

```
(gdb) backtrace
#0  clear (this=0xabd4e8) at /usr/include/c++/4.7/bits/basic_string.h:801
#1  ping (this=0xabcf40) at ./lib/dbdriver.h:465
#2  mysqlpp::Connection::ping (this=<optimized out>) at ./lib/connection.cpp:243
```

The crash is also always triggered from the secondary thread, when both threads are connected to the MySQL database (runs fine when the main thread is running an artificial while(true) loop)

Connection code:

```
    mysqlConnection = new mysqlpp::Connection(false);
    mysqlConnection->set_option(new mysqlpp::ReconnectOption(true)); // Reconnect if session times out

    if(!mysqlConnection->connect("fakeDbName", "fakeHostName",
                                 "fakeUserName", "fakePassword))
    {
        printf("Failed to connect..\n");
    }

    if(!mysqlConnection->thread_aware())
    {
        printf("Mysql++ not compiled with threading support\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Mysql++ compiled with threading support\n");
    }
```

I followed the guidelines from Mysql++, configuring/compiling with '--enable-thread-check' and linking with 'libmysqlclient_r'. I'm getting a 'Mysql++ compiled with threading support' printf once connected. I'm also creating a separate connection object for both threads.

Any thoughts, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You could put a semaphore around your database access to rule out some thread-safety problem in the mysql library.  But I'm curious why you need separate threads here... it seems like the action of the sending thread is tied directly to the receiving thread.  Why can't you do both in the same thread?